Jenkins' dark theme hardcoded the IP info into the code made dynamic IP virtual machine loading page SLOWER over 10 seconds?
The virtual machine used Jenkins very smoothly at the beginning, but one day suddenly the Jenkins page loaded very slowly. The page that could be loaded within 1 second before was often taken more than 10 seconds to load. But it is not the kind of stuck that cannot be loaded at all. All functions can be used normally, but the loading time is extremely long.
Use F12 of the browser to check the elements and find that there is an element called theme.css that often takes more than 10 seconds to load, and this element needs to be loaded every time a page is jumped.
Then I found theme.css hardcoded the IP which is when I installed the Jenkins and plugins. But my VM IP is dynamic. It will change after some time later.
Request IP is http://192.168.11.131, but my VM IP is http://192.168.11.137.
Hardcode
After forbiden the dark mode plugin and restart the Jenkins, I found the pages could be load in normal speed.
I'm wondering if the problem really related to the dark mode hardcoded IP, and if my IP is dynamic, then I cannot use the dark mode plugin then?

The URLs in a page should be relative, not absolute, where possible.

Check the Jenkins URL setting for your installation, it's under Manage Jenkins - System - Jenkins Location. That's where the old IP might be coming from:

